# selenium python product load button not working

Tags: python, selenium

This [page](https://www.billigvvs.dk/maerker/grohe/produkter?min_price=1) has a total of 790 products and I write selenium code to automatically click on the product load button until it will finish loading all 790 products. Unfortunately, my code is not working and getting an error. here is my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time


driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url ='https://www.billigvvs.dk/maerker/grohe/produkter?min_price=1'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

#accept cookies 
try:
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='coi-banner__accept']").click()
except:
    pass
    print('cookies not accepted')

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load.
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='productbox__info__name']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()


#my page load button not working. I want to load all 790 product in this page 
products_load_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filterlist__button']").click()
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='filterlist__button']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

The error message saying Unable to locate element but see the picture which saying I am selecting the right element. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an extra space at the end, try with this:

```py
products_load_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filterlist__button ']").click()
```

when you work with selectors is always a good practice to copy and paste directly from the page, that will save a lot of headaches in the future.

**Edit:**

The while loop to check if all the elements are loaded looks similar to this:

```py
progress_bar_text = driver.find_element_by_css("div.filterlist__pagination__text").text

# From here you could extract the total items and the loaded items
# Note: I am doing this because I don't have access to the page, probably
# there is a better way to found out if the items are loaded taking
# taking a look into the attributes of the progressBar

total_items = int(progress_bar_text.split()[4])
loaded_items = int(progress_bar_text.split()[1])

while loaded_items < total_items:
    # Click the product load button until the products are loaded
    product_load_button.click()

    # Get the progress bar text and updates the loaded_items count
    progress_bar_text = driver.find_element_by_css("div.filterlist__pagination__text").text
    loaded_items = int(progress_bar_text.split()[1])
```

This is a very simple example and does not consider a lot of scenarios that you will need to handle to make it stable, some of them are:

1. The elements might disappear or reload after you click the `products_load_button`. For this I'll recommend that you take a look to explicit waits in selenium docs.
2. Is possible that the progress bar could disappear/hide after the load is complete.

Comment: you can write a while loop and continously get the value from the progress bar, if the value of uploaded products is equal to the value of total products then you `break` the loop and do whatever action is needed.

Comment: The problem was fixed after I used Firefox. I think chrome might have any issue. Again Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, I see that you are using `time.sleep(20)` for the page to wait to load. This is generally a bad practice because the time that a page takes to load i usually dynamic. You should take a look to [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), this will help you to choose an element within the page so you could tell if is already loaded or not

Comment: I am not understanding how to write loop for string with number. can you please show me an example?